# Promisify for Observables in RxJS5

Tags: javascript, callback, rxjs, bluebird, rxjs5

Is it possible to create observables similar to how Bluebird's `promisify` works?

Reference: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html

#### Regular way to handle callbacks

```
someFunc = callback => handleCallback(callback)
```

#### Handling callbacks with a Promise

```
someFunc = callback => (
    new Promise(resolve => handleCallback(resolve))
    .then(callback)
)
```

#### Fancy Bluebird wrapper around manually handling callbacks with a Promise

```
someFunc = callback => (
    Promise.promisify(handleCallback)()
    .then(callback)
)
```

In the same vein, a similar requirement is required for observables:

#### Observable Creation

```
someFunc = callback => (
    Rx.Observable
    .create(observer => (
        handleCallback(() => observer.next())
    ))
    .subscribe(callback)
)
```

#### Callback Observable Wrapper

```
someFunc = callback => (
    Rx.Observable
    .fromCallback(handleCallback)
    .subscribe(callback)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is with the `bindCallback` method.

The solution to this problem would be:

```
someFunc = callback => (
    Rx.Observable
    .bindCallback(handleCallback)()
    .subscribe(callback)
)
```

Since `bindCallback` returns a function, the arguments you'd pass in before the final callback arg are passed into the returned function.

There's also `bindNodeCallback` which is exactly the same except the first arg returned is a possible error message as you'd normally see in Node.js callbacks.

Since both of these methods only fire once and then automatically get unsubscribed, you may want to use `fromEventPattern` instead depending on your needs. It will keep firing `observer.next()` anytime the callback is called.